# function that shifts letter however so many times to the right in the alphabet

Tags: python

```
def character_shift(letter, number)
    letter = [A,a,B,b,C,c,D,d,E,e,F,f,G,g,H,h,I,i,J,j,K,k,L,l,M,m,N,n,O,o,P,p,Q,q,R,r,S,s,T,t,U,u,V,v,X,x,Y,y,Z,z]
```

If I entered `character_shift(A,2)` I would want the program to return 'C'.. or character_shift(z,1) to return 'a'... but I'm not very sure how to make it shift.. or wrap back around once it gets to the end of the alphabet.

I was thinking of assigning each letter to a variable i.e var1 = (A,a) then performing lots of ifs, elifs... but not really sure tbh

Would it be possible to use the most basic of methods/functions/operators to help me explain it or at least give me a start on how to go about it without writing the function out for me. Either would be appreciated.

Comment: Have a look at [`ROT13`](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ROT13) for some ideas on how to implement this.

Answer (score 0):

You could use

```
str.maketrans() #for python 3
string.maketrans() #For python 2
```

This takes two string arguments or one dictionary. The argument on the left is the starting letter and the one on the right is what it will be changed to.

```
table = str.maketrans('abc','def')
print('abc'.translate(table)
```

For your needs, if you put the string 'abcdefghijjlmnopqrstuvwxyz' (excuse typing I am on a phone) and on the right of the comma you used 'cdefghijklmnopqrstuvwxyzab' this would move them all two places.

Answer (score 0):

```
>>> UPPER, LOWER = ord('A'), ord('a')
>>> def character_shift(text, shift):
    ... data = list(text)
    ... for i, c in enumerate(data):
    ...     if c.isalpha():
    ...         base = UPPER if c.isupper() else LOWER
    ...         data[i] = chr((ord(c) - base + shift) % 26 + base)
    ... return ''.join(data)

>>> character_shift('This is a test.', 0)
'This is a test.'
>>> character_shift('This is a test.', 1)
'Uijt jt b uftu.'
>>> character_shift('This is a test.', 2)
'Vjku ku c vguv.'
>>> character_shift('This is a test.', 26)
'This is a test.'
>>> character_shift('This is a test.', 3)
'Wklv lv d whvw.'
```

You can of course just send a single letter to the function instead of an entire string and it will still work fine.